# How to filter results by sql_attr_uint in sphinxapi?

Tags: php, mysql, api, search, sphinx

I have `sql_attr_uint = category` in my sphinx config.

How can I filter results with sql_attr_uint in sphinxapi?
for example I would like to sort results based on `test` and where category is `13 or 23 or 77`

```
$results = $sp->Query("test", "index"]);
```

Comment: Whats the value of $query ?

Comment: @Lee `test` - the search term. I've no idea now to include `category` filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, i'll just say the bit of PHP code you decided to remove, will have inhibited other people being able to help, as they won't know how you are connecting to the sphinx search engine and what type of query you are performing (as you can use SQL style queries as well as "CLI style" queries).

Anyway, from that bit of code, it was obvious your using the PHP Sphinx client documented on php.net. To that end, you hould use this :http://www.php.net/manual/en/sphinxclient.setfilter.php

So you would do this before the query method (where $SP is your sphinx client object):

```
$SP->setFilter('category', array( 12, 23, 77) );
```

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm. Edited back the code. How can I set `Query` to search everything? so I can sort only by filter?

Comment: You could try `*` as your query, however, sphinx is not a data store, its a text search engine. As part of your sphinx configuration, you will have had to set a parameter along the lines of prefix/suffix indexing. Which will mean sphinx will only index from a specific length. If your min length is 3, you will need at least 3 characters before/after your `*` for a successful search (assuming you have `enable_star` set to true). To be honest, assuming your using a  mysql datastore as your source, you should be using a direct mysql query if your not going to actually be using the text search.

Comment: I've tried that already, min length is set to 1                                        `$results = $sp->Query("*", "index");` and I have `enable_star` set to true. it work only with combination of a character. I thought I could optimize further some parts of my website as sphinx is ultra fast compared to mysql.

Comment: Sphinx is a full text replacement as i said. I don't think you can just do a wildcard search. Even the additional filtering of category id will be done "post query" if i understand sphinx correctly. So what you want to do is tell sphinx to get ALL records, then loop through and drop the ones that don't match one of the category id's.  There is no way, in that scenario that Sphinx would ever be quicker than MySQL with an index set on the category field. If it is, then you must have messed with and totally screwed up your mysql configuration.